# quickfix doesn't correct restore session after waking up

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I've got an issue, please, look at the logs:

```
AAA is an LP
BBB is me

...
20141222-14:57:12.863 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=71 35=0 49=AAA 56=BBB 34=1326 52=20141222-14:57:12.905 10=033 
here I closed the notebook

and here opened
20141223-06:54:15.190 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=151 35=A 34=1 49=BBB 52=20141223-06:54:15 56=AAA 98=0 108=20 141=N 554=... 10=245 
20141223-06:54:15.307 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=89 35=A 49=AAA 56=BBB 34=1330 52=20141223-06:54:14.374 98=0 108=20 141=N 10=113 
20141223-06:54:15.308 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=73 35=2 34=2 49=BBB 52=20141223-06:54:15 56=AAA 7=1 16=0 10=060 
20141223-06:54:15.308 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=151 35=3 49=AAA 56=BBB 34=1331 52=20141223-06:54:14.374 45=1 371=34 372=A 373=99 58=Wrong sequence number. Expected 1319 but received 1 10=059 
20141223-06:54:15.308 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=126 35=5 49=AAA 56=BBB 34=1332 52=20141223-06:54:14.374 58=Wrong sequence number. Expected 1319 but received 1 10=192 
20141223-06:54:15.309 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=64 35=5 34=3 49=BBB 52=20141223-06:54:15 56=AAA 10=197 

20141223-06:54:35.200 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=151 35=A 34=5 49=BBB 52=20141223-06:54:35 56=AAA 98=0 108=20 141=N 554=... 10=251 
20141223-06:54:35.314 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=89 35=A 49=AAA 56=BBB 34=1337 52=20141223-06:54:34.385 98=0 108=20 141=N 10=124 
20141223-06:54:35.315 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=73 35=2 34=6 49=BBB 52=20141223-06:54:35 56=AAA 7=3 16=0 10=068 
20141223-06:54:35.316 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=151 35=3 49=AAA 56=BBB 34=1338 52=20141223-06:54:34.385 45=5 371=34 372=A 373=99 58=Wrong sequence number. Expected 1319 but received 5 10=078 
20141223-06:54:35.316 : 8=FIX.4.4 9=126 35=5 49=AAA 56=BBB 34=1339 52=20141223-06:54:34.385 58=Wrong sequence number. Expected 1319 but received 5 10=207 
...
```

As we can see after the waking up quickfix sends a logon request, and LP accepts it, then quickfix sends a resend request, but LP rejects it because request has the wrong sequence number. LP expects 1319, but quickfix sends 1. Why does it happen? May be I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is closed. It was in the incorrect StartTime and EndTime settings.